# Redirect from specific port to another port and specific path

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, servlet

How can I configure Tomcat that 
http://hostname:5555/ can be redirected to http://hostname:8080/somepath

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Apache in front of your Tomcat instance, you can do this using Apache's proxy support.  A typical solution might look like this:

```
<Location /somepath/>
ProxyPass http://localhost:5555/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5555/
</Location>
```

You'll find more information in the Apache and Tomcat documentation, and a quick visit to [Google](http://www.google.com/) will turn up lots of useful results.

Comment: The location of your Apache configuration is somewhat OS/distribution dependent, but it's usually called `httpd.conf`. On RHEL (and variants) you typically drop files into `/etc/httpd/conf.d` rather than modifying the main configuration file.  This question (and others you may have) are already well documented, and you may want to spend some time looking through the information already available to you.

Comment: I don't have apache, only Tomcat